# I formated my hard drive with bitcoin core on it

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery

First timer here

...I downloaded bitcoin core a few weeks ago until last week where it still had not synced so i started all over...I was originally waiting for BTC CORE to synchronize(I missed the part in the installation that stated I needed 220+ gb of free space)...I had to format BOOT ssd(256gb..also where I originally tried to save BTC CORE)...thats why it was taking so long and I purchased 1tb samsung evo. I'm  wondering if my BTC address will be the same(since I never actually synced with the servers and since I am not using the same SSD where BTC CORE is being saved. However, it is the same SSD that windows is booting from but I had to reinstall windows.

I have now downloaded BTC CORE on my new SSD and it is synced. Unfortunately, I cant find my BTC and when I use a block explorer the funds are not there(I checked with a BE last week and the BTC was there... but pending or waiting to sync...now its not)

...did my BTC address change? will it ever sync with the older one so I can get my funds?

hope someone can help

Answer (score 5):

Addresses are not magically tied to the hardware you use. If you delete the file that contains the private keys for your addresses, you will lose them and thus lose access to your Bitcoin.

Since it seems that you formatted your hard drive without making a backup of your wallet file, your private keys and thus your Bitcoin are lost. You may be able to recover the file using file recovery software such as [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva).

Comment: whats the name of the file i should be looking for?          I saw someone say wallet.dat but id like to confirm

Comment: The file is named `wallet.dat`.

Comment: Thanks...I found what I believe may be the lost file but when I copy/paste...then boot BTC CORE it says corrupt file and then fails